# error Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of yo

Tags: reactjs, facebook-sharer

I'm working on a project with ReactJS, a personal blogger to share articles on my Facebook profile page, I want to use facebook like and share plugins but I get the error as in the title.
Thank you for being here, have a nice day

[image error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV6xh.png)

I tried very hard to find all the similar problems but I can't solve it, someone please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.